# Get elements in a vector that are not present in other vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have the following 3 vectors:

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
vec1 <- c("a", "d", "f", "h")
vec2 <- c("b", "c")
```

I would to get a new vector that contain the elements present in vec, that are not present in `vec1` and `vec2`

output desired:

```
output <- c("e", "g")
```

Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried `setdiff(vec, c(vec1, vec2))` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `setdiff()` and use `c()` to concatenate `vec1` and `vec2`.

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
vec1 <- c("a", "d", "f", "h")
vec2 <- c("b", "c")
setdiff(vec, c(vec1, vec2))
```

Output:

```
> setdiff(vec, c(vec1, vec2))
[1] "e" "g"
```

Answer (score 0):

vec[which(!vec %in% c(vec1, vec2))]

`vec %in% c(vec1, vec2)` returns `TRUE` for elements of `vec` that are in `vec1` and `vec2` combined and `FALSE` otherwise. `!vec %in% c(vec1, vec2)` does the opposite, i.e., it returns `TRUE` for elements of `vec` that are not in `vec1` or `vec2`. `which` returnes the position index for those returned `TRUE`, which can be used by `vec[]` to extract the original elements from `vec`.